# ExtJS - Setting a message box over disabled forms

Tags: forms, extjs

So to give you an idea of what I am working with, I have a popped up modal that contains a series of individual forms in the modal. Based off the current selection, the forms will be either disabled, or enabled. If they are disabled, I would like to display a message box over the disabled form in the modal explaining why it is disabled.

I've tried using Ext.msg.alert and other forms of Ext.msg, however I am unsuccessful in getting them to remain over the forms. I can align them over the form, but upon scrolling it doesn't stay over the form, it just stays fixed in the main window position, instead of follow the form inside the modal. Is this possible to do?

I then tried to do it in a hackish way and set a loading mask over the form, which displays the message, but that as well moves when you scroll down.

I attempted to use the 'fixed' property of the components, but it seemed to do nothing.

I am not sure if I am looking at this from the wrong angle or what, but things don't seem to be working out for me.

Any ideas?

```
listeners:{
    afterlayout: function(form, eOpts){
        if(form.disabled){
            var msg = Ext.Msg.alert({title:'Disabled', modal: false, fixed: true, msg:'Blah blah blah mmmkay.'});
            msg.alignTo(form.el, 'c-c');
            //fixed
        }
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know the result. Basically, we can override the base components or write our components.

```
Ext.define('Artlantis.view.OverlayWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.overlaywin',
    defaults: {
        autoScroll: true
    },
    layout: 'fit',
    width: '50%',
    height: '50%',
    modal: true,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

// to call this component
Ext.create('Artlantis.view.OverlayWindow',{
    title: 'Disabled',
    items: [
    {
       xtype: 'panel',
       items: [
           ...
       ]
    }
    ]
});

// or call by xtype
...
xtype: 'overlaywin'
```